# Partion key issue azure cosmos db async api

Tags: android, kotlin, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

So I am attempting to create a new doc in cosmos with this code:

```
 fun newDoc(key: String, data: Any, id: String){
    policy.setConnectionMode(ConnectionMode.Direct);

    val asyncClient = AsyncDocumentClient.Builder()
        .withServiceEndpoint("https://ara-account-data.documents.azure.com:443/")
        .withMasterKeyOrResourceToken(System.getenv("IOTDB") )
        .withConnectionPolicy(policy)
        .withConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.Eventual)
        .build()
    val doc =
        Document(data, id, "user-$key")
    val options = RequestOptions()
    options.partitionKey = PartitionKey("user-$key")
    val createDocumentObservable: Observable<ResourceResponse<com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.Document>> =
        asyncClient.createDocument("dbs/Ara-android-database/colls/Ara-android-collection", doc, options, true)
    createDocumentObservable
        .single() // we know there will be one response
        .subscribe(
            { documentResourceResponse: ResourceResponse<com.microsoft.azure.cosmosdb.Document> ->
                println(
                    documentResourceResponse.requestCharge
                )
            },
            { error: Throwable ->
                System.err.println("an error happened: " + error.message)
                throw  error
            }
        )

}
```

but I am getting this error

```
an error happened: ["PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header"],
```

RequestStartTime: "20 Feb 2020 01:40:14.716", RequestEndTime: "20 Feb 2020 01:40:18.003", Duration: 3287 ms, Number of regions attempted: 1

any help would be awesome :}

Comment: Can you edit your question and include the document you're trying to send. Also tell us the name of the partition key attribute. It seems the partition key value specified in the document does not match with partition key value (`user-$key`) in the header.

Comment: this method is used for a variety of tasks (the reason why the data is in the 'any') the format for the key is user-someid and IS the same on both uses. pls note I can create documents without a key.

Comment: The partition key must reside on the object and also make sure "user-$key" is the same as you have defined at the time of the creation of the container.

Comment: will do I am a little busy this morning but I will get back to you soon.

Comment: It looks like my key element, which starts with an upercase letter was being transferred to lower case by the document generator I had to manually convert to json using GSON. so there was no key in the document. I will be posting issue on the azure api later today.